# Synchronizing TCP messages

Tags: multithreading, tcp, tcpclient

I have minimum 3 TCP client, each has a Thread. I'm sending out messages and waiting for the answer, but sometimes I have to wait to receive the response from all client, this is depending what kind of message sent the server out. I already made to send messages to the clients and receiving, but when I have to wait for the other client response I couldn't do that until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you didn't mention your environment/language, I assume C#/.NET 4

You need a mechanism for each client to signal the arrival of a response. This is usually done with AutoResetEvents: Each client sends his response back to the server. The server itself can extract from the reponse (or any other property, e.g. the connection) with client has sent it. Then he sets the apporpriate AutoResetEvent.

The thread that formerly initiated sending the message can afterwards wait for all AutoResetEvents to be set.